# Access a pointer of a record inside another pointer

Tags: delphi

Imagine the following record:

```
type
  PSocket_Tunneling = ^TSocksServer_Socket_Tunneling;
  TSocksServer_Socket_Tunneling = record
    Socks_Queue: array of byte;
  end;
```

Socks_Queue, dynamic array, I learned recently that it's a pointer.

Ok, now we allocate this record, inside another pointer:

```
var
  Socket_State: PSocket_Tunneling;
begin
  GetMem(Socket_State, SizeOf(TSocksServer_Socket_Tunneling));
  try
    Socket.Data:= Socket_State;
   with PSocket_Tunneling(Socket.Data)^ do
   begin
     SetLength(Socket_State.Socks_Queue, 10);
   end;
  except
    FreeMem(Socket.Data);
    Socket.Close;
  end;
end;
```

Socket.Data is a pointer. The SetLength line, gives me access violation (raised exception class $C0000005 with message access violation...).

How I should access the array of bytes correctly?

Comment: This is not related to your crash, but your `with` statement is useless since you are not accessing the record fields via the `with`, you are accessing the local variable directly instead. If you want to use `with` correctly then drop the `Socket_State.` from the `SetLength()` statement, otherwise just get rid of the `with` (which you should do anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use `GetMem` and `FreeMem` for a managed type. That's a mistake because they do not initialize and finalize the managed type. Note that it is managed because it contains a dynamic array. It would be managed if it contained an interface, a string, a variant and so on.

Solve the problem by using `New` to allocate and `Dispose` to de allocate. These exist to do what `GetMem` and `FreeMem` do not do, that is initialize and finalize managed types.